# Connect two monitors to MacBook 4,1

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video-adapter

All I can find on the internet is info on MacBook Pros. I have a regular MacBook, model 4,1, with a Mini DVI and a Fire Wire port. Currently I'm connecting an external monitor using a Mini DVI to HDMI converter.

Is it possible to connect two monitors to a MacBook 4,1 (Snow Leopard), using either a combo of Mini DVI and Firewire, or a splitter on either port?

Answer (score 1):

According to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-early-2008-penryn-specs.html) that machine can only support one external monitor, at 1920x1200 resolution.